# Создание PDF документа на Windows Phone

Tags: c#, pdf, .net, mobile-development, windows

Необходимо создать PDF документ на Windows Phone (Lumia, Windows 8.1).

Ищу подходящий компонент (лучше **.NET C#**) для создания клиента десктопного приложения. Нужно, чтобы, помимо создания, ещё умел заполнять формы и подписывать документ (поддержка сертификатов).

Интересно, это выполнимая задача для телефона или нет, учитывая ограничения по памяти и ограничения доступа к файлам системы. Загугливая, нашёл **иксфинум**, но он только делает вид, что работает, с русскими шрифтами не умеет создавать читаемый документ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [nuget.org](http://nuget.org) много пакетов  для работы с PDF. Например [этот](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Apitron.PDF.Kit.Mobile), думаю, подойдёт как для Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight , так и для Windows Store приложений.
Создать простую таблицу, форму, отчёт можно, достаточно удобно. Актуальную документацию и примеры кода можно найти [здесь](http://apitron.com)

Comment: Нашёл ещё книжку https://www.scribd.com/doc/257380618/Apitron-PDF-Kit-in-Action